# WordPress: Main nav links with children aren't working on mobile?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I'm currently making a WordPress page and for some reason when the menu collapses all the menu items with children stop working. I don't know any JavaScript (yet) or really anything more than basic HTML and CSS so I'm a little over my head trying to figure out why this is happening. I've tried going into devtools to make sure the href is still there and it is so I'm not sure what else to look for at this point. Any suggestions would be awesome.

The site is [here](http://www.bridgetwilliams.site/187_portfolio).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stop working"? How would you use the menu items when the navigation is collapsed?

Comment: So when it is collapsed and then opened, the top level menu items (about, multimedia and photography) stop loading the pages their supposed to when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your child menu items seem to be working fine when the nav is collapsed (on mobiles etc). The child link item are set to display:block!important when collapsed which is why there are appearing all the time, and not just when the parent is hovered over, like on desktop screen widths.

If want the child links to appear only then the parent is selected, then try removing display block from your style.css as below. Personally I think it is more useable as it is though.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px)
ul.slicknav_nav ul {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thats helpful and good to know but not quite what the issue is. Did you see how when you look at the menu on mobile and try to click any of the parent items (which all have pages linked to them) the links don't work. I don't know why this would happen especially when they do work when the menu is viewed on desktop.

Comment: I believe Adam might be on to something. At a quick glance, I believe that the script is designed to have the second level hidden initially on mobile as well, and only revealed when you click on one of the first level points. You will also see that it is using a `slideUp` animation on the second level menu when you click on the first level - sometimes at least. Maybe you don't need slicknav at all? Most of it can be done with media queries with relative ease.